# Dictionary values come back with slashes '\' removed?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I saved few directory locations to a `Dictionary<string, string>`,

e.g.

```
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\abc\\123
```

But the value that gets stored in the dictionary is `C:\WINDOWS\system32\abc\123`

So when I later compare a value against one in the dictionary it does a comparison like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\abc\123
```

to this

```
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\abc\\123
```

How can I retain backslashes when storing values in a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are expecting? Paths shouldn't have double backslashes in them (except at the start for UNC). Are you confusing what you see in the debugger (with escaped backslashes) and other places that you see the strings?

Comment: You should scape \\ character.
How are you saving the string?

Comment: @MatthewWatson seriously ? that coming from a senior member of community :S

Comment: @TimSchmelter but I can see dictionary is adding duplicate values though..

Comment: @CustomizedName You edited the question since I asked my question - so I guess it's not the difference between what you see in the debugger and elsewhere. However, I feel sure you shouldn't be storing actual double backslashes in a path string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I didn't changed anything other then title of question and second I am not storing path in double backslashes, I am getting it from IIS manager developed by IIS, so i will let them know about your suggestion :-) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dict.Add(key, @"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\abc\\123");
```

`\` is an escape character. Adding `@` makes your string a string literal instead.

EDIT I've reproduced your issue and this fix will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the @ symbol in front of the strings when saving. That should solve it.